# Gatling: requests inside foreach loop not having the same number of executions

Tags: gatling

I have this script:

```
.foreach("${list}", "item") {
  exec(http("Req 1")
    .post("/path/to/service/one")
    .formParam("param1", "${item}")
    .formParam("param2", "somestring")
    .formParam("param3", "${param3}")
    .check(xpath("/xmlroot/id").saveAs("id"))
    .check(xpath("/xmlroot/version").saveAs("version")))
  .exec(http("Req 2")
    .post("/path/to/service/two")
    .formParam("param1", "${param1}")
    .formParam("param2", "${param2}")
    .formParam("version", "${version}")
    .formParam("id", "${id}")
    .check(status.is(200)))
  .exec(http("Req 3")
    .post("/path/to/service/three")
    .formParam("id", "${id}")
    .formParam("param1", "somestring")
    .formParam("param2", "${item}")
    .check(xpath("/xmlroot/@id").exists))
}
```

It executes successfully, but it reports that there are only 2 `Req 2` requests executed while there are 8 of `Req 1` and `Req 3`. I expect there to be an equal number of requests.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Edit:
It seems to be completing different number of requests each run, where it only tries to run as many `Req 2` requests as it can fit in the amount of time `Req 1` and `Req 3` runs. Are they fired simultaneously? I assumed these are fired one after the other.

Edit2:
[image: screenshot of results]
Here is a screenshot of one of the reports generated. It shows that `Req 2` executed 75% less times, and that the requests are also around 3 times slower than `Req 1` and `Req 3`.

Edit3: Setup and scenario:

```
  val scenario = scenario("Scenario")
    .exitBlockOnFail {
      exec(loginAction,
        actionThatEndsWithTheLoop)
    }

  setUp(scenario.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))
    .assertions(global.successfulRequests.percent.is(100))
    .protocols(httpProtocol)
```

I only run 1 user so all of the 8 iterations are expected for each of the requests.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just showing that only 2 of them were successful? `exec` calls as you listed above execute in sequence, so I don't see how it would be possible to have fewer Req2 than Req3. Can you show the report?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that only 2 were sent and both were successful, no failed requests. I can show the report when I get back to the office next week.

Comment: Attached screenshot of the report.

Comment: Can we see the actual code of (a) the `setup` call, and (b) any scenarios run by `setup`?

Comment: Is it possible that you have other request with identical names? How is populated your list? Req2 is not bound to item.